# ACR122U Not Connecting after First NFC Scan with nfcpy library

Tags: pi-4, rfid, nfc

I am trying to read an nfc card from my ACR122U-A9 with a raspberry pi, but it only works the first time after it is plugged in. After I clf.close(), I can't open it again without plugging it back in. I used "pip install -U nfcpy" for install and I am working in a venv for python. I am ssh'd into the pi4B from my laptop although that shouldn't affect anything.

It swaps between these error codes : 110. Connection timeout, 2. Cant find device 5.IO error 16. Resource Busy, usb1.USBErrorOverflow: LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW [-8]

Some examples:

1. File "/home/brent/Projects/BarBox/.virtualPy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/usb1/**init**.py", line 119, in raiseUSBError
   raise __STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION_DICT.get(value, __USBError)(value)
   usb1.USBErrorTimeout: LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT [-7]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "/home/brent/Projects/BarBox/.virtualPy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nfc/clf/transport.py", line 316, in read
raise IOError(errno.ETIMEDOUT, os.strerror(errno.ETIMEDOUT))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
usb1.USBErrorBusy: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY [-6]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "/home/brent/Projects/BarBox/.virtualPy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nfc/clf/transport.py", line 291, in open
raise IOError(errno.EBUSY, os.strerror(errno.EBUSY))
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy

```
import nfc

def on_connect(tag):
    print("Tag detected!")
    print(tag)

usb_id = "usb:072f:2200"
count = 0

with nfc.ContactlessFrontend() as clf:
    clf.open(usb_id)
    tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda eh: False})
    print(tag)
```

I have probably spent 8 hours trying to solve this and nothing seems to work, I would really appreciate the help.
I have also tried closing with clf.close() but no difference

Thank you for the help!